# Essential singularity at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following function $$f\left ( z \right )=\frac{\left ( z^{2} -9\right )^{2}\ln z}{\left ( z^{2}-5z+6 \right )^{3}e^{\frac{1}{\ln\left ( 1+z \right )}}}$$ where $\ln$ denotes the principal value of $Ln$
It is trivial to show it has poles at $z=3$(of order 1) and $z=2$(of order 3), however checking for singularities at $z=\infty$ seems a bit harder, and considering the function $g\left(z\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ makes it  only look messier. One can intuitively tell that numerator vanishes in comparison with the denominator, and that $$\lim _{z\rightarrow \infty}f\left ( z \right )=0$$
How should I try to approach this problem to show analytically that it is indeed the case?